# omniauth alway got low level oauth_token from twitter

Tags: ruby, permissions, twitter, twitter-oauth, omniauth

1.
updated app's "Access Level" to "read, write, and direct messages".
(two days ago at dev.twitter.com/apps)

2.
lastest omniauth gem.

> ```
> gem update omniauth
> Updating installed gems
> Nothing to update
> ```

3.
oauth via web.

```
   use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :twitter, APP_API_KEY, APP_SECRET
    end
```

4.
got oauth_token/oauth_token_secret correctly. 
CAN read mentions form twitter. 
**but CAN NOT** read direct message.

5.
the @testuser's oauth_token at dev.twitter.com/apps/xxxxx/my_token is:

'AAAAAAA' (Permission Level is RWD)

6.
the oauth_taken got via omniauth is

'BBBBBBB' (Permission Level is RW)

```
  get '/auth/twitter/callback' do
    omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']   
    oauth_token = omniauth['credentials']['token']
```

Question is :
How can I get the high level(RWD) oauth_token via omniauth?

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of omniauth.

I create a issues,and software-project@github submit a pull request today.
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/pull/395

Due to lates Twitter API changes the authorize_path in omniauth should update too.

source Diff:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/pull/395/files

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried omniauth-twitter gem? It should work with latest omniauth.

https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter